# Quelle est la différence entre les pronoms « en » et « y » ?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, en, y

Une différence que je n'ai jamais comprise, c'est la différence entre les pronoms *en* et *y*. Quand utilise-t-on *y* et pas *en* ?

Comparez :

> Les banquiers ont trop d'argent. Je n'en ai pas assez.

et :

> J'ai du mal à comprendre la différence entre le français et
>   l'anglais sur ce point ; j'y réfléchirai demain.

Dans chaque cas, en anglais, *en* et *y* sont traduits par *it*. Comment puis-je comprendre la différence ? Est-ce qu'il y a une règle ?

Comment: Le second exemple est incorrect : le verbe *considérer* est transitif. Ce devrait être *Je considérerai cela demain*.

Comment: Ah merci - j'ai fait cette exemple très vite...!

Comment: Le second exemple est typique du *parler lyonnais* : « je vais y faire » instead of « je vais le faire » par exemple.

Comment: "j'y réfléchirai" demain est un raccourci pour "je réfléchirai à cela demain", en Savoie, ou dans les régions où le "y" s'emploie beaucoup, je suis sûr que l'on peux entendre, "j'y considérerai demain"

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Un moyen mnémotechnique est le suivant :

- *en* quand on dit *de*
- *y* quand on dit *à*

Exemples :

> Je viens de l'école. J'en viens.
>
> Je vais à l'école. J'y vais.

Comment: Bonne astuce, mais pas toujours applicable c.f. les exemples de l'OP.

Comment: @Evpok: Le premier exemple de l'OP tombe dans le premier cas de ma réponse. Le second exemple est incorrect.

Comment: En français standard, peut-être. C'est tout de même le genre de phrases qu'on entend souvent en Bourgogne, par exemple, donc pas forcément indigne d'intérêt.

Comment: De mémoire, les règles pour y/en sont beaucoup plus complexes (et bourrées d'exceptions). Le problème majeur d'un tel moyen "mnémotechnique" est qu'il est essentiellement fondé sur une connaissance intuitive de la langue, ce qui ne risque pas d'aider un étudiant étranger...

Comment: @Dave, tu as un exemple d'exception?

Comment: @Joubarc: à vrai dire, plus qu'à des exceptions, je pensais à des cas qui ne suivent pas le format "à/de ⇒ y/en", tels que: "J'hésite à dire la vérité ⇒ J'hésite à **la** dire", "As-tu **un** vélo? ⇒ En as tu un?", "Je vais **chez** le médecin ⇒ J'y vais"... avec des règles imbriquées du genre: "Ce cahier appartient à paul. ⇒ **lui** appartient", *mais* "Je pense à Paul. ⇒ J'**y** pense". Bref, les joies habituelles de la grammaire française :-)

Comment: Ok, ce sont plutôt d'autres règles, selon moi, mais effectivement ça peut être dangereux pour quelqu'un qui apprend. Par contre, je n'utiliserais pas "y" pour une personne: "Je pense à Paul" => "Je pense à lui", mais je ne sais pas si c'est une règle.

Comment: Ok, je me trompe, "j'y pense" est valable même pour Paul. http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/y : _Je pensai à Anne. J'y pensai d'une telle manière que je m'assis sur mon lit, le cœur battant_ (Sagan, _Bonjour tristesse_, 1954, p. 76).

Comment: @Joubarc: toute exception peut se être considérée comme une "règle" (de faible portée) ;-) Le point important étant qu'il y a plus à retenir qu'un simple "de/à" => "en/y"

Comment: @Evpok Qu'est-ce que c'est _l'op_?

Comment: @Beatrix [Humour](http://french.stackexchange.com/q/1727/82) ?

Comment: @Evpok Non, pardon. J'ai cherché _OP_ dans le Q&A d'anglais, mais je n'étais pas sûre s'il avait le même sens ici.

Comment: @Beatrix Pas de problème, juste une drôle de coïncidence, alors.

Comment: Est-ce que l'on peut donc dire que l'utilisation du y/en est en lien avec le temps? Futur vs. Passé?

Comment: @Alex Non, l'utilisation du y/en est liée à la préposition à/de.

Comment: Je viens de l'école? Je reviens de l'école. Je viens de Paris (mon origine). C''est plutôt, j'arrive de l'école. Enfin......revenir/arrive de/ contre venir de (une origine). A mon avis, on ne peut pas venir de l'école.

Answer (score 10):

"y" typically translates to "there" and often replaces a prepositional phrase introduced by à, chez, en, dans, etc. (most prepositions EXCEPT for "de").

> I go to the beach. - I go there.
>
> Je vais à la plage. - J'y vais.
>
> I'm going to eat in the restaurant. - I'm going to eat there.
>
> Je vais manger dans le restaurant. - Je vais y manger.

"y" can also replace phrases formed as "à + {noun}" when that noun ISN'T a person

> Do you play soccer? - Yes, I do.
>
> Joues-tu au foot ? - Oui, j'y joue.

but

> I call Jacques. - I call him.
>
> Je téléphone à Jacques. - Je lui téléphone.

The pronoun "en" has many uses. One is to replace prepositional phrases introduced by "de":

> Are you coming from the stadium? - Yes, I am (coming from there).
>
> Est-ce que tu viens du stade ? - Oui, j'en viens.

It also replaces nouns introduced by partitive articles (de, de la, du, des):

> Do you want some water? - Yes, I do (want some).
>
> Veux-tu de l'eau ? - Oui, j'en veux.

"en" is also used with {verb}+de expressions:

> Do you play the piano? - Yes, I do (play it).
>
> Joues-tu du piano ? - Oui, j'en joue.

And again, it's used with expressions of quantity (beaucoup, assez, trop, etc.) followed by "de":

> Do you have enough money? - Yes, I have enough.
>
> As-tu assez d'argent ? - Oui, j'en ai assez.

note: the expression of quantity (assez, in this case) is still in the sentence with "en", after the verb

"en" is also used with numerical expressions of quantity. If there is a specific number of something, that number is still in the sentence.

> Do you have any brothers? - Yes, I have two. / No, I don't.
>
> As-tu des frères ? - Oui, j'en ai deux. / Non, je n'en ai pas.

Summary: "y" replaces prepositional phrases introduced by anything other than de, and "en" does most everything else that has to do with "de".

Remember order, as well.

> Are there any apples? - Yes, there are three.
>
> Est-ce qu'il y a des pommes ? - Oui, il y en a trois.

It also comes before the verb it applies to:

> She is going to make some
>
> Elle va en faire

[Source](http://www.reddit.com/r/French/comments/uomhd/can_someone_explain_the_use_of_y_and_en_simply_to/c4x7czk)

Answer (score 4):

**En** together with **y** are *adverbial pronouns*. They both replace an *antécédent*, i.e. a complement previously mentioned in the context.

- **En** replaces a complement introduced with **de** (i.e. with a sense of *genitive* or *ablative*);
- **Y** replaces a complement introduced with **à** (i.e. with a sense of *instrumental*, *accusative* or *locative*, but **not** *dative*!)

For instance:

> Les parents sont fiers de leur enfant. Ils en sont fiers. *(ablative)*
> Il revient de la poste. Il en revient. *(ablative)*
> La vie est une fleur. L'amour en est le miel. *(genitive)*
>
> Il est passé à la poste. Il y est passé. *(accusative)*
> L'entreprise gagnerait à déployer ses activités. L'entreprise y gagnerait. *(instrumental)*
> Il est parvenu à sa destination. Il y est parvenu. *(locative)*

**Not!**

> Il commence à manger. <s>Il y commence</s>. *(dative)*
> Il donne donne une croquette à son chien. Il **lui** donne une croquette. *(dative)*

Also, because French's indefinite articles for uncountables or undetermined plurals are built on a genitive / ablative, you will find:

> As-tu du pain ? Oui, j'en ai.
> As-tu des pommes? Oui, j'en ai.

What is more, it can be used with the undetermined article **un** or rather with cardinal determiners like **un, deux, trois,** etc. In which case you have to understand the implicit genitive *il a pris une pomme (indéterminée parmis les pommes qui existent)*.

> Il a pris une pomme. Il en a pris une.
> Il a pris cinq pommes. Il en a pris cinq.

Be careful! **en** and **y** always come last in a series of pronouns.

> Il a donné une croquette à son chien. Il lui en a donné une.
> Parle-lui-en d'abord.
> Donne-m'en plus. <s>Donne-moi-z-en plus</s>

Comment: I do not understand why French speakers insist on using Latin case explanations for French syntax problems. Must I remind you that, aside from personal pronouns (just like English), French np longer has cases.

Answer (score 2):

**The applications of "en":**

1- "en" can replace with "indefinite articles + nouns":

> Tu veux une banane?
>
> Merci, j'en prends une.

2-"en" can replace with "the proposition de/du + nouns":

> Il y a de la soupe?
>
> J'en veux beaucoup.

-in definite quantities:

> Un kilo de farin?
>
> J'en prends la moitié.

3-"en" is used for places that are preceded by "de"

> Tu es parti de Bordeaux ce matin?
>
> Oui, j'en suis parti à 10h.

4-"en" is used when "de" follows the verb:

> Je rêve **de** devenir cantatrice.
>
> J'en rêve.

**The application of "y" :**

1- "y" is used with places that are preceded by a preposition other than "de":

> Ils vont à l'école ?
>
> Oui,ils y vont.

2- "y" is used when "à" follows the verb:

> Il répond **à l'invitation**?
>
> Il y répond .

Answer (score 0):

*Y* pour remplacer un lieu où l'on va. *Je vais à la banque.* – *J'y vais.*

*En* pour remplacer une quantité. *Je mange deux tartines.* – *J'en mange deux.*

Comment: Non, comme l'indique la réponse acceptée, on dit « j'en viens » pour dire « je reviens de X. »

Answer (score -1):

## Emploi des pronoms personnels

SI LE PRONOM PERSONNEL REPRÉSENTE UN MOT, CELUI-CI DOIT EN PRINCIPE FIGURER EXPLICITEMENT DANS L'ÉNONCÉ.

- On sait que le pronom personnel peut tenir lieu de toute une proposition :
  Arrias a tout lu, a tout vu, il veut *le* persuader ainsi.

  - S'il représente un mot seul, il convient que ce mot soit explicitement formulé dans la phrase. Ainsi l'énoncé suivant n'est pas satisfaisant :
    Ses parents le choient comme *le* sont peu d'enfants.
  - Certes, beaucoup d'écrivains utilisent ce tour, qui était tout à fait courant dès l'époque classique. On peut cependant estimer que c'est exiger beaucoup du lecteur que de ramener à induire directement la forme du participe d'une forme personnelle du même
    verbe. Le cas est peut-être plus acceptable, estiment certains grammairiens, lorsque le verbe appartient au groupe des verbes à l'infinitif en *-er* et qu'il figure dans la phrase précisément sous la forme de l'infinitif :
    Fais servir ton pouvoir à mieux aimer ce qui peut *l'* être encore.
     L'infinitif a ici la même physionomie phonétique que le participe, et la forme de celui-ci est ainsi directement suggérée. Mais on peut à bon droit trouver étrange une phrase telle que celle-ci :
    Je me propose de lui écrire tout ce qui doit *l'* être.
    Mieux vaut encourir le risque d'une répétition: avec un peu d'habileté, on pourra donner à celle-ci l'allure d'une énergique insistance - ce qui ne saurait disconvenir à ce type d'énoncé :
    Tout ce qui doit lui être écrit, je *l'* écrirai.
    Au lieu de 
    Je voudrais vous rassurer comme je *le* suis moi-même.
    nous pourrons écrire
    Je suis rassuré, et je voudrais faire en sorte que vous *le* soyez autant que moi.

    ---
  - On dira : 
    Êtes-vous la malade? - Je *la* suis.
    Êtes-vous malade? - Je *le* suis.
    Il y a là, en effet. une opposition grammaticale qui est en même temps une opposition sémantique. Dans le premier cas, *la* remplace un nom normalement déterminé dont il prend la marque de genre et de nombre: dans le second cas, au contraire, *le* tient lieu d'une qualité exprimée par un adjectif, et marque le neutre qui, en français, a dans ce cas la même forme que le masculin.
  - Si le nom n'est précédé d'aucun article défini ou d'aucun adjectif déterminatif. le pronom qui renvoie à ce nom a la marque du neutre :
    Ah! si j'étais mère! - Vous *le* serez un jour.
  - Si le nom est précédé d'un article indéfini, il convient d'utiliser une autre tournure pronominale :
    Êtes-vous un honnête homme? - Oui, j' *en* suis un.

ELLIPSE DU PRONOM «*LE*, *LA*, *LES*» DEVANT «*LUI*».

- L'usage classique admettait l'ellipse (haplologie) du pronom *le*, *la*, *les*, complément d'objet direct, devant *lui*, *leur*, complément d'objet second.
  Est-ce donc vous, Madame, qui avez dit à votre mari que je suis amoureux de vous? - Moi? et comment *lui* aurais-je dit?
- L'usage actuel n'admet pas ce type d'ellipse : le pronom complément d'objet direct doit être exprimé.
  Cette erreur, je *la* *lui* avais signalée.

## Emploi des adverbes pronominaux « en » et « y »

- D'abord. *en* et *y* étaient des adverbes de lieu indiquant, l'un l'origine, l'autre la situation ou la destination. Ils le demeurent encore aujourd'hui dans des phrases très courantes telles que celles-ci :
  Vous allez à Paris? - J' *en* viens.
  Vous venez de Paris? - J' *y* vais.
- Cet emploi s'est ensuite étendu à d'autres types d'énoncés dans lesquels *en* et *y* n'assument plus de valeur adverbiale et ont fonction de complément d'objet, de complément de nom, ou même de complément d'adverbe ou d'adjectif. Ce sont alors des pronoms personnels comme les autres.
  L'amour vrai a ses trésors; il n' *en* fait point le compte.
  Si tu vois quelque chose qui te donne à penser. tu m'*en* avertiras tout doucement.
  Il est gênant et fatigant de faire figure de grand homme : ceux qui s'*y* plaisent font pitié.
- L'usage classique permettait d'employer *en* et *y* pour tenir lieu de noms de personnes :
  Quant à moi, mon père, il *en* faut juger autrement.
  Rien ne peut me distraire de penser à vous, j'*y* rapporte toutes choses.
- *En* et *y* sont employés pour représenter des noms de personnes quand ils permettent d'éviter la répétition de *lui*, *elle*, *eux*, *elles* :
  Vous vous souvenez d'elle? Oui, je m'*en* souviens. 
  Vous vous intéressez à lui? Non. je ne m'*y* intéresse pas.
- *En* représente en outre un nom de personne : 
  Et s'il n'*en* reste qu'un, je serai celui-là.
  Il aime sa cousine et il *en* est aimé.
  Dans ce dernier cas, *en* se trouve en concurrence avec la forme *de lui*, *d'elle*; on préférera résolument l'emploi de en chaque fois qu'il permettra d'éviter une répétition :
  Êtes-vous aimé d'elle?  Oui, j'*en* suis aimé.
- *Y*, en dehors de l'emploi dont nous avons parlé, est utilisé beaucoup plus rarement pour représenter un nom de personne, en concurrence avec les pronoms personnels correspondants. Quelques rares verbes s'accommodent de cet emploi : ainsi rêver, se fier :
  Souvent femme varie. Bien fol est qui s'*y* fie.
  Celle-là lui avait paru jolie : il *y* rêvait donc, et à son mari.
  Vouloir oublier quelqu'un, c'est *y* penser.