# Existe-t-il un équivalent français de « OP » ?

Tags: traduction, usage, terminologie

Le terme anglais *Original Poster* et son abréviation *OP* très couramment utilisée dans les forums en anglais ont-ils un équivalent en français ?

Parce que dire à chaque fois *celui qui a démarré le fil*, ça fait un peu long quand on est pressé, *OP* c'est tellement plus rapide !

Comment: On peut utiliser le prénom/surnom du "OP". C'est tellement [c☺☺l](http://youtu.be/3SPH5Vz-LgY).

Comment: Ni le prénom, ni le pseudo ne contient l'indication qu'il s'agit de celui qui a fait le premier post. D'où la pertinence du terme anglais

Comment: même en anglais OP veut plus souvent dire "operator" par exemple sur IRC

Comment: @Knu: *OP* signifie en anglais [beaucoup de choses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OP), **dont** *Original Poster*. Voir sur [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_forum#Thread)  et [ici](http://netforbeginners.about.com/od/internetlanguage/f/What-Is-OP.htm). C'est un terme couramment utilisé sur Stackexchange : maths, apple, EL&U, stackapps, fitness, etc. Et voir [meta.stackoverflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79804/whats-stackexchange-ese-for-op). De nombreux forums en anglais l'utilisent avec le sens de *Original Poster*, en contexte il n'y a aucune ambigüité.

Comment: Et aussi largement employé sur la plupart des listes de diffusion qu'il m'a été donné de lire, toujours avec le même sens d'auteur du premier message du fil.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

On pourrait utiliser *PO* comme *Posteur Originel*, histoire de ne pas trop s'éloigner de l'acronyme d'origine, en considérant *posteur* dans sa [définition "informatique"](http://www.lexique-informatique.com/P/poster.html).

Comment: Je vois effectivement en cherchant sur google que le terme que tu proposes est employé. Est-il adopté par la communauté des habitués des forums -ce que je ne suis pas sinon je n'aurais pas posé la question, bien sûr-  ou d'autres termes sont-ils parfois utilisés ?

Comment: Ou posteur original.

Comment: @wok originel et original n'ont pas le même sens, même s'ils sont souvent confondus...

Comment: @PhiLho Je suis d'accord, c'est pourquoi je suggère "original" ici.

Comment: Prenons un exemple pour achever de vous convaincre : http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%A9dition_originale

Comment: OK, mais je préfère `originel` ici, le posteur (vilain anglicisme, d'ailleurs, non ?) à l'origine du fil de discussion, plutôt que "créant un sujet neuf", ce qui est de toute façon rarement le cas (dans les forums que je fréquente, les mêmes questions reviennent souvent !).

Comment: @PhiLho D'après [la réponse de Laure](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/8248/pourquoi-neuf-mais-pas-nouveau-dans-quoi-de-neuf), il serait "créant un sujet nouveau", plutôt que "créant un sujet neuf" dans ton commentaire; n'ai-je pas raison?

Answer (score 7):

Le problème récurent des abréviations du web, c'est qu'elles ne seront pas reconnues partout. Alors lorsqu'il s'agit de traductions, on n'est pas sorti de l'auberge !

Ce genre de choses dépendent du site ou du forum sur lequel on se trouve. Je prends pour exemple le nom de ce petit tchat qui se trouvent parfois sur le bord d'une page web. Certains sites l'appellent un « mini-chat », d'autre une « chatbox », d'autre une « shoutbox », etc.

Quand on en vient aux forums, c'est la même chose. Selon les sites, ces termes représentent la même chose:

- rubrique, forum, …
- sujet, thread, fil, …
- message, post, réponse, …

Personnellement, je n'ai jamais lu « OP » sur un forum, simplement parce que nous ne fréquentons pas les mêmes.

Je pense que c'est très compliqué (et peu utile) de chercher une traduction exacte à cette abréviation. Les différents forums ont sans doute quelque chose correspondant. S'ils n'en ont pas, tu n'as qu'à en choisir une (**PO** comme l'a proposé Cédric, **OP** sans traduction, **PP** pour Premier Posteur, **preum'**, **initiateur**, …), la placer dans quelques messages et attendre que quelqu'un te demande « keske sa veu dir ? ». Petit à petit, ça rentrera dans les habitudes des utilisateurs et ils l'utiliseront.

Comment: *L'initiateur du fil de discussion* me parait être une bonne dénomination, mais *l'initiateur* seul est peut-être un peu ambigu et *l'initiateur de la question* semble incorrect. Sinon, le *preum's* sera en général reconnu comme l'auteur du premier commentaire sur un blog (celui qui aura été le plus rapide à ne rien apporter à la discussion, la plupart du temps).

Answer (score 6):

1. Je garderais **OP** pour d'évidentes raisons de compréhension mutuelle¹.
2. J'y verrais la jolie forme *Originel Posteur*, en vertu de ce que [«](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/327/1514) les adjectifs qui classent un nom dans un ensemble de manière absolue se placent en général avant le nom [»](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/327/1514). [Bah quoi ?](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%A9troacronymie)

J'ai aussi rencontré « **primoposteur** », qui rend pas trop mal.

---

¹ <sup>Au fond, ceux qui vont comprendre une forme courte et pas tout à fait explicite (≠ « auteur du premier message ») sont avant tout ceux qui connaissent la forme anglaise de départ.</sup>

Comment: pas mal le "primoposteur" :)

Comment: Oui, primoposteur j'aime aussi. Par contre, on bien est d'accord, à la troisième utilisation ça va finir en PP.

Comment: Je ne trouve pas le point 2 correct, on dit *pêché originel*, le nom est en premier.

Comment: @n.1, il y a là (http://french.stackexchange.com/a/327/1514) une foultitude de cas particuliers parmi lesquels j'ai trouvé une justification (ad hoc) à ma rétroacronymie. Bien sûr, la plupart du temps, les adjectifs vont après les noms, et s'il ne s'agissait pas de justifier **OP**, je dirais *Posteur Originel*.

Answer (score 3):

J'ai tendance à dire **Initiateur** (du fil, du thread, de la discussion, etc.).

C'est relativement court, sans ambiguité, et pas "trop" guindé.

Comment: Et puis ça ne fait pas du tout "société secrète" non plus :·)

Comment: *Initiateur* tout court, oui éventuellement, mais bon si on se met à pinailler, je jette mon tablier ;-)

Answer (score 2):

La majorité des sujets de forums n'étant pas anonyme, pourquoi ne pas se référencer au pseudonyme de l'auteur du sujet ?

Par exemple ici, je pense que @Laure a voulu dire que …

C'est en tout cas ce que j'ai toujours vu ou de simples dérives comme l'*auteur du sujet* qui n'est pas trop mal non plus sinon …

Je n'ai jamais vu les autres utilisations sur les forums francophones.