# Pourquoi « neuf », mais pas « nouveau » dans « quoi de neuf » ?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire, usage, adjectifs

J'étais stupéfait par la simplicité et, du même temps, par l'étrangeté de cette expression; s' origine-t-elle dans une quelconque phrase latine, ou est-ce que la raison est l'usage des formes courtes des adjectifs?

Y a-t-il une différence sémantique entre « neuf » et « nouveau » ?

Dans quelles circonstances peut-on dire ou écrire « de nouveau » ? Est-que c'est d'usage correct ?

Comment: Ce n'est pas la question, et c'est peut-être même incorrect (je n'en trouve aucune trace sur internet), mais il me semble qu'il y a aussi l'expression « du nouveau sur ...? » Par exemple « Est-ce qu'il y a du nouveau sur l'affaire Leonarda? »

Answer (score 8):

Neuf vient du latin *novus* qui veut dire récent. Le latin *novus* a parallèlement dérivé dans le latin *novellus* qui a donné l'ancien français *nouvel* devenu nouveau au XIII<sup>e</sup>.

**Neuf** et **nouveau** n'ont pas le même sens, même si en langage populaire ils sont parfois employés comme synonymes. Neuf veut dire « qui n'a pas encore servi » alors que nouveau veut dire « qui est de création récente ». C'est à dire que je peux très bien avoir une paire de chaussures qui ne sont pas nouvelles, puisque ça fait dix ans que je les ai dans mon placard, mais qui sont neuves parce que je ne les ai jamais sorties de leur boite.

**Neuf** a aussi depuis le XIII<sup>e</sup> siècle le sens de « original » (pour une idée par exemple).

**Neuf** et **nouveau** sont des adjectifs qui peuvent être substantivés, ce qui est le cas dans « Quoi de neuf ?. D'après Alain Rey cette expression serait apparue au début du XIX<sup>e</sup> siècle.

Comment: juste en passant :  IXX ? je connais pas ce chiffre romain.. Ne serait-ce pas XIX pour 19 ?

Comment: @Laure: ces *ème* récurrents, pas récurant ;-)