# The pronouns "en" and "y"

Tags: pronoms, en, y

According to the question [La différence entre "en" et "y"](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/66/quelle-est-la-difference-entre-en-et-y-utilises-en-tant-que-pronoms),
I have another question:

Is it possible that we use "en" and "y" in one sentence? For example in the below sentence can we replace "de sucre" with "en" and "dans le gâteau" with "y"? (both of them). If yes, what's the order of these pronouns?

> Combien de sucre je mets dans le gâteau?

Comment: notice to the answer of Stéphane Gimenez to this question:“Direct Object Pronouns” and “Indirect Object Pronouns”,it is useful.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, it is possible and very common. You must put **y** before **en**.

Exemple:

> Des bonnes questions sur StackExchange, j'y en ai vues.

- **y** stands for "StackExchange".
- **en** stands for "bonnes questions".

Modern usage in France tends to omit the *y* altogether.

[image: j'y en,j'en y]

Comment: C'est aussi possible dans certaines variétés orales où *y* remplace un autre pronom, par exemple *lui* « J'y en ai mis une sévère, de raclée. ».

Comment: Actually, no. In your example sentence, *y* is part of the idiom “il y a”, it does not stand for “StackExchange”. A better example sentence would be “Des bonnes question sur Stack Exchange, j'y en ai vu.”

Comment: On dit plutôt «Des bonnes questions sur StackExchange, j'en ai vu.».

Comment: According to your chart "Modern usage in France tends to omit the y altogether", is is not "very common" as you first said. It even seem to be dramatically deprecated. http://pisantorni.wordpress.com/2008/02/09/en-et-y-ensemble/

Comment: @Skrol29 [Claire Blanche-Benveniste](http://books.google.fr/books?id=C15ZGEwZ13MC&pg=PA105&dq=%22j%27y+en%22&hl=fr) analyse l'incompatibilité de *y* et *en* comme une règle structurelle (*Pronom et syntaxe: l'approche pronominale et son application au français*, §2.2.5, règle 3), comme l'impossibilité d'enchaîner deux pronoms personnels primaires.

Answer (score 4):

I don't see why we couldn't use both in one sentence. In your example, that would be:

> *Combien j'en y mets ?*

However, it doesn't sound so natural to say that, maybe because of the lack of precision on the context and because you are asking a question. I would rather say:

> *Combien j'en mets dans le gâteau ?*
>    or
>   *Combien j'y mets de sucre ?*

In a conversation, "*Combien j'en mets ?* " would be enough:

> -Met du sucre dans le gâteau s'il-te-plaît.
>   -Combien j'en mets?

Comment: When we use _y_ et _en_ in an answer, e.g., _Y a-t-il des livres dans le placard? Oui, il y en a._ Doesn't sound natural too? I mean, it's proper in an answer?

Comment: @Beatrix: In that case, "*Oui il y en a*" is the right answer. I was just stating that "it doesn't sound so natural" in the OP example.

Comment: « Combien j'en y mets ? » doesn't sound natural, but « Combien j'y en mets ? » does…

Comment: @Otiel: I mean that is it possible because of its meaning, If I replace both of them it isn't clear, there is a ploblem in meaning, isn't it?

Comment: @Oltarus: I wouldn't say it *does* sound natural on this question, but it does sound *more* natural, yes.

Answer (score 3):

Quand on utilise deux pronoms compléments ,on les place dans l'ordre suivant:

[image]

Comment: @Gilles:I wrote it myself! I'm sure that this is useful.

Answer (score 2):

"**y**" et "**en**" ne s'emploient jamais ensemble sauf dans "**il y en a**".

On ne dit pas :

> Des bonnes questions sur StackExchange, j'y en ai vues.

mais :

> Des bonnes questions sur StackExchange, j'en ai vues.

(Et *vu* s'accord avec *en*)

Comment: Ah non, « jamais », c'est beaucoup trop fort, même si c'est vrai qu'on a tendance à omettre le *y*.

Comment: C'est probablement plus qu'une tendance. Sauriez-vous citer un livre connu, pas trop ancien, qui pratique le "y en" ensemble ? Sur sur le web on trouve les deux thèses, et pourtant il semble qu'un ouvrage de référence énonce que "y" est "en" ne peuvent pas être ensemble. http://pisantorni.wordpress.com/2008/02/09/en-et-y-ensemble/

Comment: Bon, j'admets que les usages récents, disons [1981–2000](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22j%27y%20en%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1981,cd_max:2000&lr=lang_fr), semblent être toujours des réimpressions d'ouvrages plus anciens ou l'usage populaire de *y* pour *lui*. Donc « *j'y en* » semble bel et bien avoir disparu. Je me demande pourquoi d'ailleurs, cette forme m'a l'air grammaticalement sans reproche, pourquoi est-elle tombée hors d'usage ?