# How do you say “I’m tearing some off of it.”

Tags: pronoms

---

This is a question which has occurred to me after asking [this question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/43195/how-do-you-say-i-m-tearing-some-fabric-off-from-it).

---

---

---

**Here is the scenario: There is some fabric which *BELONGS TO* a jacket and this is the case in A, B and C.**

---

### A

I would like to say ***“I’m tearing some fabric off of the jacket.”*** with the idea that the fabric belongs to the jacket being implied.

The translation would be ***« J’arrache du tissu de la veste ».***

---

### B

Also,

***“I’m tearing some fabric off of it.”*** = ***« J’en arrache du tissu ».***

---

### C

Also,

***“I’m tearing some off of the jacket.”*** = ***« J’en arrache de la veste ».***

---

### Questions

(1) BUT how would I say ***“I’m tearing some off of it.”*** where, by the word “some” I’m talking about the fabric and by the word “it” I’m talking about the jacket to which the fabric belongs?

(2) I have the feeling there is no translation for “I’m tearing some off of it.” because we can’t say ***« J’en en arrache. »***. <— Is this statement correct ?

(3) If (2) is correct then I feel like the best we could do is **B** or **C** or I’ll just have to use « J’y en arrache .» to say “I’m tearing off some from there.” where, by the word “there” I’m referring to a location on the jacket. Is this correct?

---

If the translations in **A**, **B**, or **C** are incorrect please let me know.

---

Please also note that my french level is beginner therefore please can you keep all explanations as simple as possible. Thank you!

Comment: Can you please take into account what I said before? In English, we say: to tear fabric off of it. not: from it. If the English is wrong, it is very difficult to translate it accurately. Anyway, j'arrache du tissus [au/a] is: to tear some fabric off [x]. the DU is SOME Veux-tu du cafe? Do  you want some coffee? [My accents are not working right now.]

Answer (score 1):

***I’m tearing some off of it*** would theoretically be translated to:

> (incorrect:) **J'en en arrache**.

but this sequence of two joint pronouns (*pronoms conjoints*) is agrammatical.

Assuming you really don't want to repeat any of the complements, the way to handle this conflict is simply to merge the pronouns in a single instance with what is called an haplology (*haplologie*), leading to:

> ***J'en arrache.***