# What does “en” mean in “l'amour en est le miel”?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms

> La vie est une fleur. L'amour en est le miel. – Victor Hugo

It's translated as “*Life is a flower. Love is the honey.*”

But what does **en** mean there? Why isn't it translated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It could be more clearly translated to

> Life is a flower. Love is **its** honey.

In the translation you provided, this relation could be implicitly understood

> Life is a flower. Love is the honey *(of this flower)*.

Comment: Chipotage, mais j'aurais plutôt dit que *en* réfère à *la vie*. *Le miel de la vie* c'est quand même autrement plus poétique que *le miel de la fleur*, non ? Enfin, bref…

Comment: Chipotage toujours, mais plus que `le miel de la fleur`, c'est surtout `le miel de cette fleur`, qui garde un joli soupçon de poésie, non?

Comment: En effet, ça marche bien mieux. J'ai mal détraduit :)

Answer (score 3):

**En** together with **y** are *adverbial pronouns*. They both replace an *antécédent*, i.e. a complement previously mentioned in the context.

- **En** replaces a complement introduced with **de** (i.e. with a sense of *genitive* or *ablative*);
- **Y** replaces a complement introduced with **à** (i.e. with a sense of *instrumental*, *accusative* or *locative*, but **not** *dative*!)

For instance:

> Les parents sont fiers de leur enfant. Ils en sont fiers. *(ablative)*
> Il revient de la poste. Il en revient. *(ablative)*
> La vie est une fleur. L'amour en est le miel. *(genitive)*
>
> Il est passé à la poste. Il y est passé. *(accusative)*
> L'entreprise gagnerait à déployer ses activités. L'entreprise y gagnerait. *(instrumental)*
> Il est parvenu à sa destination. Il y est parvenu. *(locative)*

**Not!**

> Il commence à manger. <s>Il y commence</s>. *(dative)*
> Il donne donne une croquette à son chien. Il **lui** donne une croquette. *(dative)*

Also, because French's indefinite articles for uncountables or undetermined plurals are built on a genitive / ablative, you will find:

> As-tu du pain ? Oui, j'en ai.
> As-tu des pommes? Oui, j'en ai.

What is more, it can be used with the undetermined article **un** or rather with cardinal determiners like **un, deux, trois,** etc. In which case you have to understand the implicit genitive *il a pris une pomme (indéterminée parmis les pommes qui existent)*.

> Il a pris une pomme. Il en a pris une.
> Il a pris cinq pommes. Il en a pris cinq.

Be careful! **en** and **y** always come last in a series of pronouns.

> Il a donné une croquette à son chien. Il lui en a donné une.
> Parle-lui-en d'abord.
> Donne-m'en plus. <s>Donne-moi-z-en plus</s>

Comment: See more on: http://grammaire.reverso.net/3_1_26_en_pronom.shtml; http://grammaire.reverso.net/3_1_54_y_pronom.shtml; http://french.about.com/od/grammar/a/pron_adverbial_2.htm

Comment: Your answer would be a perfect fit for this question: http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/66/quelle-est-la-difference-entre-en-et-y-utilises-en-tant-que-pronoms