# Use of 'en' and 'y'

Tags: pronoms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Quelle est la différence entre « en » et « y », utilisés en tant que pronoms ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/66/quelle-est-la-difference-entre-en-et-y-utilises-en-tant-que-pronoms)

I have a question about the use of 'en' and 'y' together.

Imagine I would like to say:

- Have you just arrived from Paris?
- No, I'm going there next month.

How it would be using the pronoun in the second phrase?

- Tu viens de arriver de Paris?
- Non, j'(en/y) vais le mois prochain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a quick rule of thumb, (I mean, for people not having read [this](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/66/quelle-est-la-difference-entre-en-et-y-utilises-en-tant-que-pronoms?rq=1) question) :

> 1) **y** replaces **à** (*to*)
>
> 2) **en** replaces **de** (*from*)

- Je vais à Paris --> J'y vais.
- Je viens de Paris --> J'en viens.

---

So, to answer more directly :

> Tu viens d'arriver de Paris?
>
> Non, j'**y** vais le mois prochain.