# Le pronom « en » peut-il remplacer toute une proposition ?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms

> [**Je n’ai pas poussé la curiosité** et je n’en avais pas la disponibilité](http://www.liberation.fr/politiques/2013/07/16/compte-de-cahuzac-en-suisse-taubira-ne-s-est-pas-posee-la-question_918629).

Dans ce cas, il semble que *en* remplace l'ensemble de la première proposition (*d'avoir poussé la curiosité*), n'est-ce pas ?

Si j'ai raison, j'aimerais savoir quand est-ce qu'il possible de remplacer toute une propostion par ce pronom.

Comment: pourquoi utiliser ce nouveau tag, "grammaire-appliquée"?

Comment: @AlexisPigeon 1. Because I can. 2. (Seriously) Because my question is about grammar in context, that is, applied to a specific context. So I thought this new tag would introduce a badly needed (in my opinion, at least) nuance: _theoretical grammar_ (as in "what does _en_ mean?") vs. this _grammaire appliquée_ (as in "_en_, in this context, works like this, doesn't it?"). [My French is still not good enough to express all I've said in this comment; hence my using English for it.]

Comment: Fair enough. But in that case, could I suggest you edit the tag wiki then, and add that explanation? http://french.stackexchange.com/tags/grammaire-appliquee/info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dans le cas présenté dans la question, la réponse est oui. *En* se substitue à *pousser la curiosité* et *je n'en avais pas la disponibilité* se substitue donc à *je n'avais pas la disponibilité de pousser la curiosité*.

Un complément introduit par la préposition *de* peut en général être remplacé par le pronom *en*, comme décrit dans les réponses à [cette question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/66/quelle-est-la-difference-entre-les-pronoms-en-et-y). Une proposition entière peut dans certaines circonstances être remplacée par *en* ou *y* :

> Paul vient demain. Je m'*en* rappelle, et j'*y* pense.

Je me rappelle que Paul vient demain, mais la formulation est « se rappeler **de** quelque chose », d'où le pronom *en*. Et je pense au fait qu'il va venir demain, la formulation est « penser **à** quelque chose », d'où le pronom *y*.

---

Cette phrase est perfectible. Cela est dû au fait que *pousser la curiosité* est d'un registre plutôt familier.

Autre exemple :

> *Je parviendrai à faire cela car j'en ai le temps et les moyens.* (*car j'ai le temps et les moyens d'y parvenir*)

Comment: C'est claire. Mais pourquoi _d'y parvenir_? _Y_ en ce cas remplace quoi?

Comment: @indoxica: *y* et *en* réfèrent tous les deux à « faire cela », mais « on a le temps et les moyens **de** faire cela », alors qu'on « parvient **à** faire cela ».

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Je compris. (Je le crois.) Si oui, « on a le temps et les moyens **de** faire cela » est pour _en_ et « parvient **à** faire cela » est pour _y_, n'est-ce pas?

Comment: Je m'attendais à cette question :) *Y*, ici, se substitue à *à (faire) cela*. *Y* et *en* ne se substituent pas aux mêmes choses, on ne peut pas les interchanger. Certaines questions de ce site parlent de cela. Tu auras également besoin de la définition de *y* (http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/y - onglet 2, sens II. [Y, pron. équivaut à une constr. indir. et représente un nom, un pron. ou une prop. entière]) et de celle de *en* (http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/en - onglet 2, sens II. B. 1. [L'antécédent représente une prop. antécédente, ou une idée parfois vague tirée du cont.]-*En* = *de cela*).

Comment: Désolé, une fois raccourci de façon à ne pas excéder la longueur autorisée, mon commentaire ci-dessus est illisible.

Comment: @Shlublu Merci quand même :)

Comment: @Shlublu: Dois-je éditer ? (Utiliser *à* alors que l'original utilisait une structure avec *de* c'est rendre la chose incompréhensible inutilement.)

Comment: Si tu as une idée, bien sûr, avec plaisir !

Comment: Done. Pour la familliarité de l'expression, je ne suis pas vraiment d'accord. Puis n'oublie pas de qui vient la citation, je ne crois pas que la ministre emploie souvent d'expressions familiaires lorsqu'elle s'exprime publiquement.

Comment: Hélas, occuper un poste ministériel ou présidentiel n'implique pas de s'exprimer convenablement. Merci pour l'édit !

Comment: Je n'ai pas dit qu'elle le devait à son poste. [Plusieurs auteurs](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22pousser+la+curiosit%C3%A9%22&lr=lang_fr&tbs=lr%3Alang_1fr&tbm=bks&oq=%22pousser+la+curiosit%C3%A9%22) ne se privent pas.

Comment: Effectivement. L'expression serait moins familière que je l'aurais cru, alors. En même temps, de prestigieux auteurs utilisent des tournures familières dans leurs écrits... Peut-être une question à venir, si je ne trouve pas de réponse claire, tiens.

Answer (score 2):

Oui et non.

Ici « en » ne remplace pas littéralement toute la proposition : uniquement « [pousser] la curiosité ».

Sans le « en » on pourrait reformuler comme ça :

> ... et je n’avais pas la disponibilité de pousser la curiosité.

Answer (score 2):

Dans l'ATILF, *EN*, [sens 2](http://atilf.atilf.fr/dendien/scripts/tlfiv5/visusel.exe?21;s=1804899180;r=1;nat=;sol=10;):

1. En tant que pronom, *en* se construit avec un antécédent de nature substantive, qu'il s'agisse d'un subst. proprement dit ou d'un pronom qui le représente, ou d'un subst. inclus dans une loc. adv., **ou enfin d'une prop. reprise en tant qu'entité globale après nominalisation implicite par *en*.**

Donc oui (et dans ce cas précis), *en* remplace la proposition complète.