# Comment dit-on « Let's do it » en français ?

Tags: usage

Comment dit-on « let's do it » en français?  Par exemple, lorsque mon amie me propose de faire des révisions en français, et que je pense que c'est une bonne idée, je veux dire « let's do it. »… Si je dis « faisons le », « on en va » ou « on y va »,  est-ce que c'est possible ? Ces propositions ont l'air bizarre…

Comment: Note au passage: « on en va » est incorrect. On peut dire « on s'en va », ce qui veut dire « we are leaving ».

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dans le contexte que tu décris je propose :

> - Allons-y !<sup>1</sup>
> - C'est d'accord !
> - Ça marche !

Je les ai classés du plus normal/neutre (mais pas vraiment soutenu) au plus familier.

*Faisons-le* n'est pas possible dans ce contexte à cause de l'emploi de « le ». Il faudrait dire « faisons-ça » mais je ne le dirais pas tout seul dans ce contexte, à la rigueur après une des trois expressions que je propose ci-dessus.

<del>*on en va*</del> <sup>2</sup> n'est pas possible, ce serait uniquement *on y va*. Mais je n'emploierais pas *on y va* dans ce contexte mais plutôt l'équivalent à l'impératif qui marque ici la décision qui est prise, ce qui rend le mieux l'anglais *let's*.

<sub>1. Being such a *Doctor who* fan as I am, I [just can't resist this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VuogEwWS8O8.). I apologize for the noise.</sub>
  <sup>[Allons-y and the tenth Doctor](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Allons-y).</sup>
<sub>2. Pour la différence d'emploi entre *en* et *y* voir les réponses à [cette quetion](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/66/358).</sub>

Comment: I would also suggest « C’est parti », but I’m pretty sure it’s not worth an answer by itself.

Comment: « C'est parti » implique l'action immédiate alors que « let's do it » peut indiquer le future (« let's do it tomorrow ».)

Comment: Merci Laure!  Le clip de Allons-y allonso de "Doctor Who" est trés drôle, qui m'aide me souvenir.  Bonne journée!

Answer (score 3):

**Faisons ça** is a correct translation. 
But in this context I would just say **OK** or **D'accord** or **C'est d'accord**.

**On en va** is wrong: it doesn't mean anything in French.

**On y va** means that you have to or agree go somewhere right now. For exemple, you agree to go to the restaurant.

Answer (score 1):

Here in Billsburg, VA, we're lucky enough to have a very fine restaurant called "Le Yaca", short for "Il n'y a qu'a [le faire]," which kinda means "Ain't nothin' to it but to do it" and from there you could get to "Let's do it!"

Also, I've heard "On y est, allons-y!" or even just: "On y est!" used to show total agreement with the proposal (and that you're so anxious to begin that you have all but started already).

Answer (score 1):

Pour ma part, je dis souvent

> On est partis ?

Answer (score 1):

Une autre version répandue dans le langage courant est :

> Allez, faisons le !

Answer (score 0):

Je pense que dans l'exemple, il est possible de dire:

> *Au travail !*

Answer (score -1):

« C'est parti » ou « Carrement » me semblent adéquats, on les utilise dans le langage courant.

Comment: Pierre, je ne me souviens pas avoir entendu quelqu'un dire « carrément » dans le sens « faisons le ». Par contre, peut-être que tu l'entends comme « d'accord » ? Est-ce correct?