# What is the function of "-y" after a word?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, impératif

I've found this phrase in one of my games, but I don't know what is the "-y" for

> "Affectez-y 10 citoyens pour produire des matériaux de construction."

Comment: If you could provide us with more context, it'd be easier. It refers to a place most likely. If there are any instructions previous to that, it's probably referring to placing 10 citizens/villagers in the place where you can produce construction materials.

Comment: In the english version it asks me to place 10 workers in this scierie , also found this other phrase:
"Le niveau de la scierie détermine le nombre maximal de travailleurs pouvant y produire des ressources."

is it saying "the maximum of workers that can work HERE"?

Comment: Yes. "Y" basically means *à + un lieu*. "Le niveau de la scierie détermine le nombre maximal de travailleurs qui peuvent produire des ressources à la scierie."

Comment: You helped me a lot, if you wish the points, put it as an answer. thx gl

Comment: No problem. But you might find this question helpful and I believe yours has been already answered there: http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/66/quelle-est-la-diff%C3%A9rence-entre-les-pronoms-en-et-y

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*-y* is used to avoid repetition by referring to a previously mentioned entity.

> Construisez **une usine**.
>
> Affectez-**y** 10 citoyens pour produire des matériaux de construction.

Here *-y* refers to *une usine* mentioned in the previous sentence. So the sentence means:

> Affectez **à l'usine que vous avez construite** 10 citoyens pour produire des matériaux de construction.

In English this would be:

> Build **a factory**.
>
> Assign **it** 10 citizens to produce building materials.

In English this *it* has the same usage as *-y* does in French.

Answer (score 1):

*Y* is a pronoun.

In your case, *y* replaces a noun or a noun group introduced by *à* or its derived forms (*aux*, *au*), because the verb *affecter* (to appoint or to assign, in this context) is used with the *à* in French.

> Affectez 10 citoyens **à cette tâche** pour produire des matériaux de construction.

The exception to this rule is when the noun is a person.

> J'écris à ma mère. → Je lui écris.
>
> Je pense à mon père/ma mère. → Je pense à lui/à elle.

*Y* should be placed before the verb, but in your example there is an inversion because of the use of the "impératif". *Y* is therefore placed after the verb with a hyphen for the link.

Note: *y* is also used to replace a location (introduced by *chez*, *dans*, *sur*, *à*…), but this is not your case.