# Why the need to include "y" in the phrase "t'y retrouver dans"

Tags: expressions

> Ce dossier t'aidera à **t'y retrouver dans** les contrats que tu accepteras.
>
> Thanks to this file, you’ll be able to **keep track of** the contracts you accept.

Considering that "y" usually takes the place of a "dans/sur" element, why do you need to use both "y" and "dans..." in this instance?

Also, do I accurately capture the meaning of the expression "t'y retrouver dans"? I think it is used rather figuratively here, not referring to finding your bearings geographically.

Comment: *s'y retrouver* is more to "find your way around",  "way around" → *y* (lieu). "Keep track" implies future work, *s'y retrouver* / "find your way around" implies a present need. Anyway, in both "keeping track" and just as in *s'y retrouver* you do  have the idea finding your bearings geographically in the pile of papers.

Comment: To @Laure: Now that I think about it, if you said "**te retrouver** dans les contrats", it would mean "**accidentally end up** in the contracts" (which doesn't make any sense), correct? Merci.

Comment: Yes, it could mean that if taken literally, but I doubt anybody would take it literally. It took me a couple of days to come up with a credible explanation. As usual will write one in English if necessary

Comment: On peut regarder aussi du côté de _s'y connaître en_, un bel exemple de redondance, qu'on dit attribuable à la difficulté à analyser l'antécédent du pronom dans certains cas... le tour classique est _se connaître en_, dit LBU14 ; évidemment ça diffère d'un exemple où l'idée du lieu est plus claire...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La question revient à demander si **se retrouver** et **s'y retrouver** ont des sens semblables dans leurs emplois figurés.

On trouve de fait l'emploi des deux mais il me semble que chacun exprime une nuance différente. J'arrive à mieux expliquer mon raisonnement en parlant de comptes (ou de comptabilité).

> Je ne me retrouve pas dans ces comptes.

→ J'exprime le fait que je pense qu'il doit y avoir une erreur quelque part, les comptes ne tombent pas justes.

> Je ne m'y retrouve pas dans ces comptes.

→ J'exprime le fait que tout est en désordre : postes mal attribués ou oubliés par exemple, mais je ne pense pas forcément à une erreur de calcul, bref les choses ne sont pas à leur place, d'où la présence du *y*.

**S'y retrouver** peut aussi avoir le sens de « rentrer dans ses frais ». Par exemple :

> L'entreprise qui entretient les abribus ne prend pas d'argent mais ils affichent de la publicité gratuitement et donc ils s'y retrouvent largement.

Passons aux contrats.

> Ce dossier t'aidera à t'y retrouver dans les contrats.

→ Ce dossier t'aidera à retrouver la place de chaque contrat, à les classer.

> Ce dossier t'aidera à te retrouver dans les contrats.

→ Ce dossier t'aidera à comprendre les contrats.

Comment: "Se retrouver" dans tes exemples est le même que "je ne me retrouve pas dans cette description qu'on fait de moi" ? D'ailleurs je pense qu'il y a une autre subtilité, on peut employer le "y" pour le premier cas si on tourne la phrase pour qu'il y ait besoin de ce pronom: "- Et alors ces comptes ? - Rien à faire, je ne m'y retrouve pas", semble pouvoir faire référence à "se retrouver" et "s'y retrouver".

Comment: To @Laure: Come to think of it, the same goes for the following usage of "comprendre", right? At first glance, "y" and "à ce charabia" seem to be duplicate, so to speak. Merci. "J’**y comprends** rien du tout **à ce charabia**."

Comment: @LUNA Indeed, you can say the use of *y* in your example is pleonastic. I can't see the difference in meaning between *je ne comprends rien à ce charabia* and *je n'y comprends rien à ce charabia*. I had an afterthought about another figurative meaning of *s'y retrouver* which I'm going to add to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

> Ce dossier t'aidera à t'y retrouver dans les contrats [...]

*"Y"* makes reference to *"dans les contrats"* which is a rather common construction but usually requires a comma which has probably been dropped because of usage:

> Ce dossier t'aidera à t'y retrouver, dans les contrats.

There are other similar phrasal verbs like:

- S'y plaire
- S'y habituer
- Y gagner
- Y voir (plus) clair

I think that the presence of *"y"* just makes it easier to immediately pick one meaning from all the possible meanings of the different verbs. Common usage made them phrasal verbs.

Answer (score -1):

The literal translation of this sentence would be: "This folder will help you to find you there, in the contracts that you will accept."
Which implies more like the meaning, that you will not get lost in your contracts (i.e. the pronoun "y" substitues for some place between contracts, so it is a bit idiomatic).

Just if you want to know more on pronouns "y/en":
There are two pronouns like this "y" and "en". You use y, if you want to substitute for an element, which is in context used with a verb with prep. "à" (for example *"aller à Londre"* = *"y aller"*). It is not important that it is a place, it can be whatever, that suits the situation. In case of pronoun "en" the verb is with prep. "de" (*"on parle de cette chose"* = *"on en parle"*).

Comment: We have already had numerous questions about y and en on FL. [Example](http://french.stackexchange.com/q/66/358). And that's not what the question was about. Welcome to FL.

Comment: Sorry @Laure but this question is different from the example you gave.