# What do "en" and "y" mean in these two sentences?

Tags: grammaire, sens, pronoms, antécédent

- Ou il s'imagine qu'il ***en*** est possesseur, répond le gouverneur.
- Il ***y*** trouve cette note concernant Dantès.

Could anybody explain what "en" and "y" mean in the above sentences? Would it be grammatically correct if one drops these two words in the sentences?

Comment: *en* and *y* being pronouns you need to refer to what is written before and you do not give enough context. [This detailed answer about the use of *en* and *y*](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/66/quelle-est-la-diff%c3%a9rence-entre-les-pronoms-en-et-y) will help you understand.

Comment: Or else he imagines that the is the possesor [of that thing]. He finds [there] this note concerning Dantes.

Comment: @hunter: thanks for your comment. Do you mean "...he is the possessor..." instead?

Comment: @Laure: thank you for the helpful link!

Comment: @Jack yes, sorry for the typo! I can't edit it because it's a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is not in the posted lines but in Alexandre Dumas's book.

***[En](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/en)*** is a pronoun with an antecedent which is ***quelque trésor*** and ***[y](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/y)*** is also a pronoun referring to ***le registre des prisonniers***

Removing ***en*** would make the first sentence incomplete.

Removing ***y*** would just remove an explicit information.

Comment: Very informative and helpful. Thank you!