# Why did he omit "mentale" after "santé"?

Tags: vocabulaire, professions

I practice French on an application that allows users to text. I was asked about the job I was looking for and I said “je veux travailler dans le secteur de la santé mentale”. After which we exchanged more messages that led to me saying “je cherche encore un travail dans le secteur de la santé mentale”. He corrected me saying I should say “je cherche encore un travail dans le secteur de la santé”.

I inquired why *mentale* was omitted and he said because I repeated the same thing so it is redundant. But the last sentence just says *health* so it isn't accurate because the health field is broad, the job I'm looking for is specifically in mental health. I then proposed I should have said “j'y cherche encore”, the pronoun *y* should replace *le secteur de la santé mentale* but he has yet to respond.

So, how should it be said? Was he right?

Answer (score 4):

The person who corrected you was wrong. Removing *mentale* substantially changes the meaning of your sentence.

Maybe the reason why (s)he did it is *santé mentale* seems odd here. In my experience, it is not used to describe the activity sector but people's health, e.g. :

> *Je m'inquiète pour la santé mentale de ton ami.*

When referring to a job, I would say instead:

> *Je recherche (encore/toujours) un travail en psychiatrie.*

or, depending on exactly what you are looking for, which you fail to state :

> *Je recherche (encore/toujours) un travail dans le secteur de la psychologie, de l'assistance psychologique, etc.*

Comment: As far as I understand it the use of the words *Santé mentale* is  broader than *psychiatrie*. Not all jobs in mental health will be in psychiatry I expect. [This thread](https://www.infirmiers.com/forum/stage-psy-adulte-tout-secteur-difficulte-dds-autre-quest-t147846-645.html#p442323) told me more about it.

Comment: « Il faut évidemment faire une différence entre la psychiatrie et la santé mentale. On verra dans cette fiche que les deux notions peuvent se recouper mais se distinguent également. D’une façon générale, la psychiatrie renvoie à une discipline de la médecine et a donc une connotation hospitalière.  La santé mentale implique plutôt la prise en charge des personnes souffrant de troubles ou de handicaps mentaux dans le milieu ouvert. » http://www.forumedsp.org/xwiki/wiki/econnaissances/view/Notions-Cles/Psychiatrieetsantementale

Comment: @Laure Il me semblait que « santé mentale » s'appliquait plus aux pathologies plutôt qu'au secteur d'activité mais les liens fournis montrent que ce n'est pas (plus?) tout à fait le cas. Merci.

Comment: dans tous les cas on entends suffisamment rarement l'expression "secteur de la santé mentale" pour que ce soit vu comme une erreur le cas échéant (la preuve en est avec l'histoire arrivée à l'OP). Je lui recommande de ne pas utiliser cette expression au risque de passer -à tort- pour quelqu'un qui s'exprime mal.

Answer (score 3):

<strike>j'y cherche encore</strike> is not correct in this context. *Y* cannot replace *santé mentale*, because it is not a place name. You have to repeat *santé mentale* or replace it with another noun.

> Je cherche encore un travail dans ce domaine (or *dans ce secteur*).

Concerning the fist part of your question I would say you were right to repeat *santé mentale*. We do not have the entire conversation but you could have changed your mind in between the two times you talked about it. And the difference is the same in French between *santé mentale* and *santé*.

---

Edit to answer the OP's comment.

Let's imagine you were asked :

> Est-ce que vous cherchez encore du travail ?

And you wanted to replace *du travail* by a pronoun, you'd have to use *en*.

> Oui, j'en cherche toujours (encore) dans ce secteur.

You can look at the answers to this question on French Language: 
*[Quelle est la différence entre les pronoms « en » et « y » ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/66/358)*

Comment: True  y is used for location but I learned that the pronoun could also replace a previous mentioned object or idea for example: Je tiens à la vielle voiture de Maman > J'y tiens

Comment: @NathanielCatchings You can only use *y* can be used to replace a non location prepositional phrase only in the case when the prepositional phrase is introduced  by ***à*** (*au, aux, à l’, à la*) and is **not a person**.  In your sentence *chercher* does not have a prepositional phrase that requires *à.

Comment: Ok, I understand merci encore